# Understanding execution sequence with generators in python

Tags: python, generator

I have simple program that I am using to understand how generators/yeild works.

```
def learn_yield(numbers):
    for i in numbers:
        yield (i*i)

numbers = [5]

sq = learn_yield(numbers)

numbers.append(6)

for i in sq:
    print (i)
```

Here's where my understanding is unclear:

The append method is called after the call to the learn_yield function. I would have expected the output of print(i) as 25 and not

25
36

How exactly did the number 6 get sent to the function?

If I move numbers.append(6) to after the for loop, then I get the behavior I think should happen in the first place. Does this mean that the call to the function is made again when the loop is iterating?

System - PC, Windows 10
Python - 3.7 
Sublime Text

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that `learn_yield` retains a *reference* to `numbers`.  When you append to `numbers`, all code that has a reference to it will see the change.

Put another way, `numbers` in the function and `numbers` in the main code *are the same object*.

If you want to sever that link, you could make `learn_yield` iterate over a copy:

```
def learn_yield(numbers):
    for i in numbers[:]:   # [:] makes a copy
        yield (i*i)
```

For a detailed discussion of how arguments are passed in Python, see [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: Thanks. Can you also share as to why this does not apply when we move the numbers.append to after the for loop. Why does that break the reference to numbers?

Comment: @HectorM: It does not.  What happens in that case is that the number is only appended _after `learn_yield` has finished iterating_ and so it never sees the 6.